# npm package for NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable

Tags: node.js

Hello for nodejs programming, I am using visual studio community 2015 with node js tools. That environment does not have NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED process.env
variable. What is the package to install NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED variable?

Answer (score 14):

There is no package for environment variables, you just set them or not in your shell environment. For Windows if you wanted to set it you'd first do:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1
node foo.js
```

For *nix you could do something like:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1 node foo.js
```

or to make it persistent for the duration of the shell session:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1
node foo.js
```

However you really should avoid the `rejectUnauthorized` setting and if applicable, instead supply the self-signed CA when making https requests.